# With RoR ActionMailer, send plain-textmessage without using a view file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

For rendering a text (not html) message with ActionMailer in Rails 3, I see many threads instructing the programmer to make a `.text.erb` file and run the following code:

```
mail do |format|
  format.html
  format.text
end
```

...but I wish to render a very short message, without using a mailer view at all. I have success doing this in html format but not in plain text.

I use the following code:

```
mail do |format|
  format.html{ render( text: 'my text' ) }
  format.text{ render( text: 'my text' ) }
end
```

...but it sends an html email every time. What can I do to send a plain-text email and specify its content without a mailer view file?

Answer (score 2):

From [doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html):

> Action Mailer will automatically send multipart emails if you have
>   different templates for the same action. So, for our UserMailer
>   example, if you have welcome_email.text.erb and welcome_email.html.erb
>   in app/views/user_mailer, Action Mailer will automatically send a
>   multipart email with the HTML and text versions setup as different
>   parts.

Just do:

```
mail do |format|
  format.text{ render( text: 'my text' ) }
end
```

If you only want a text email.

Comment: That looks identical to the code in the original question. Am I missing something?

Comment: +1 to Brandan. @apneadiving, have you tried the suggested code? When I use it, it appears to send an html email.

Comment: sorry, forgot to delete one line :)

Comment: Okay. +1 for a working solution. But is there a way that I can do it without precluding the *option* of sending an html email? I.e. isn't there an elegant way that I could use an argument to tell the `mail` function which format to use?

Comment: the beauty of rails is that it takes the existing formats, as explained in the doc. If yo have one, it will take one, two, will take both. Just adapt your views or inline code!